# How to convert .net json string serialized by Newtonsoft to mongodb document

Tags: mongodb, json.net

```
db.logs.aggregate(
{ 
  $project : {
    timestamp:'$timestamp',
    messageObject: JSON.parse('$message')
  }
}
);
```

returns

> 2016-03-18T09:20:21.100+0330 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data :
>
> @(shell):5:20

sample record:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("56eb95e53b3d5535fc423bd4"),
  "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-03-18T05:45:08.953Z"),
  "level" : "INFO",
  "thread" : "5",
  "logger" : "AuditFilter",
  "message" : "{
      \"UserId\":\"379263f1-d638-4d94-bc91-303f3458e8fe\",
      \"ServiceName\":\"Education.Controllers.HomeController\",
      \"MethodName\":\"Index\",\"Parameters\":\"{}\",
      \"ExecutionTime\":\"2016-03-18T09:15:08.4057688+03:30\",
      \"ExecutionDuration\":380,
      \"ClientIpAddress\":\"::1\",
      \"ClientName\":null,
      \"BrowserInfo\":\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0\",
      \"CustomData\":null,
      \"Exception\":null
  }" 
}
```

Comment: `JSON.parse('$message')` is interpreted by the shell, before the aggregation query is sent to the `mongoDB` server. You would need to iterate the aggregation result and then parse the field to `JSON` when you consume it.

Comment: how can i order by message.UserId ?

Comment: You should ideally store `message` as an `object` rather than a `string`. Only then you can query on `message` as a `sub document`.

Comment: I cant store message as an object. Is there any way to convert message to sub document at query?

Comment: Fortunately, no. It does not make sense. You would have to reconsider your design.